# How to check the type of values in an array

Tags: typescript

I have a value that has the type `string[] | object[]` and depending of the type of the values in the array I want to do different things with it. Is there a way to check the types of the values in the array?

I have tried checking the type of the first item in the array, but TypeScript doesn't recognise that, so it still thinks it can be a `string[] | object[]`.
I also tried using every and check the type of every value but TypeScript doesn't allow the use of every or filter on `string[] | object[]`

Comment: Can you please add an example of what you're trying to get?

Comment: Write a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)? It's unclear why you think you can't use every, both types in the union are arrays which support that method.

Comment: use `for (const item of arr) { if (typeof item === 'string') { ... } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array is defined as `string[] | object[]`, then it makes sense to write a type predicate to find out what type it ends up being:

```
function isStringArr(a_arr: string[] | object[]): a_arr is string[] {
    return !a_arr.some(a_item => typeof a_item !== 'string');
}
```

This is how you would use it:

```
if(isStringArr(arr)){
    console.log(arr); // string[]
}
```

Checking the type in a `for` or `forEach` loop on every element is also possible, but since your array is either `string[]` OR `object[]` this doesn't make a whole lot of sense to do.

[Playground with a few examples](https://tsplay.dev/mqYMrm)

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
//check the type of variable
const isArray = Array.isArray(arr); // ️ true
console.log(isArray)
//check the type of values in array
if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
const isStringArray =
 arr.length > 0 &&
 arr.every((value) => {
 return typeof value === 'string';
});

  console.log(isStringArray); // ️ true
}
```